# To run NSTimer in background

Tags: iphone

My app is a sports app. In which the game should continue even in background, i have used nstimer for that. But I am not able to run the timer in background. whenever the app is in background the timer stops and when return it continues from same time from which it has left.

Comment: Give us a little more detail.  What is the timer responsible for updating?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot run a `NSTimer` in background - it will always be suspended unless you application have permission of playing audio in background and it continues playing audio. Till the time your background audio stops, your timer will pause..

Comment: I have used NSDateFormat  in applicationDidEnterBackground given as

Comment: Does this mean I could "cheat" with playing an audio file with no sound while using timer?