# NSTimer run in background - needs to fire every hour

Tags: ios, swift, background, nstimer

I created an app that will send text messages through an API similar to Twilio, and I have an NSTimer that fires a function every set amount of time. The problem is that if you press the home button, it will totally stop the timing, which defeats the purpose.

I have read that it is possible to have your phone play a mute sound until closed to make sure it still runs in the background, but I can't find a resource on how to do this. Here is an example: [To run NSTimer in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645175/to-run-nstimer-in-background)

If anyone has any information on how to do this, I'm sure it is very simple, and I very much appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you set up your app as a background sound playing app then yes, it is technically possible to play a "silent sound" in order to keep it active in the background, but your app will be rejected by Apple if you do this.

Apple expressly forbids what you are trying to do.

You should look at using scheduled local notifications. Those will alert the user, who can bring your app to the foreground and let it perform the desired task.

Comment: Really. Based on the number of people recommending it you would assume that it is passable. Thank you

Comment: is there any way that you would reccomend I play a sound file on the timer fire? So - every 5 minutes, I would like a timer to fire playing a "Swoosh" sent text message sound.

Comment: @Ryan I doubt you would want to do that, it would drive your users nuts and most likely get them to remove/uninstall your app. Just think how annoying a app would be that would constantly be playing a sound every 5 mins. Stick to the suggestion that Duncan made.

Comment: You likely can't have a timer running constantly at all. You could trigger local notifications every 5 minutes, and if the user acts on them, it would invoke your app. But that would be very annoying to your users. iOS apps are not meant to run constantly, and Apple will likely ban any app that tries to do that.